# How to setup and use yowsup-cli to to get Whatsapp authentication code?

Tags: python

I've tried following the same way mentioned everywhere, but something is wrong.

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dateutil python-argparse
sudo wget https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/archive/master.zip
sudo unzip master.zip
cd yowsup-master/src
cp config.example yowsup-cli.config
vi yowsup-cli.config #(Write the following according to you)
#cc=34
#phone=34123456789 #(Phone number with country code)
#id=
#password=
chmod +x yowsup-cli
./yowsup-cli --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
#status: sent
#retry_after: 3605
#length: 6
#method: sms
```

I have realized that the current archive **master.zip** is different from the one that I am supposed to find, an update maybe,

(the folder **yowsup-master/src** doesn't exist)

I tried working with the file **yowsup-master/yowsup-cli** which seemed to be the configuration file. I followed the same steps on that file but this is what I get:

```
./yowsup-cli.config --requestcode sms --config yowsup-cli.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./yowsup-cli.config", line 5, in <module>
import sys, argparse, yowsup, logging
ImportError: No module named yowsup
```

I think maybe there is a new update, has the process changed or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where the "everywhere" is from where you got the instructions that you followed, but the [yowsup page](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) is pretty explicit on Linux installation:

```
Install using setup.py to pull all python dependencies

Linux

You need to have installed python headers (from probably python-dev package) and ncurses-dev, then run

sudo python setup.py install
```

You should **not** have to download `master.zip` as `root` (`sudo`), **nor** extract `master.zip` as `root`, but you **should** follow the instructions to run `setup.py`, otherwise `yowsup` will not be installed in your dist/site-packages and `python` cannot import the package. You should have done:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
wget https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd yowsup-master
python setup.py install
cd ..
```

After that you can invoke python:

```
$ python 
>>> import yowsup
```

without an error.

The `setup.py` as used by `yowsup` has several other problems, e.g. installing argparse even if you are running newer than python2.6. `argparse` has been in the standard library since 2.7, and it is customary to test the python version before adding it to the dependency list (now, if you install using `pip27`, `argparse` will be pulled from PyPI although you don't need it).

I am not sure where your instruction got the information about copying a config file, this file is no longer available (but that has nothing to do with the actual error you encountered, and which should be solve by following the instructions).

Please file a complained with the authors of the instructions you posted about their unnecessary and potentially dangerious abuse of `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Current 'master' branch does not include    /src    , because the developer now working on yowsup2. And many blogposts - as i found - wrote on old yowsup install tutorial. But if you still want your hands dirty with old stuff, you may download the 'legacy' branch at Github.